# Blue Yeti Humming sound

Tags: usb, backgroundambience, hum

Ok here's the issue So I plugged my new Blue Yeti into my bro's computer and it had absolutely no background noise at all and it sounded absolutely amazing! (he has a 800 watt power supply) and when I tried plugging it into my pc which has a (450 watt power supply) it made a annoying humming sound and im asbolutely sure it's not from my room since I have nothing running in the background no fans no air conditioning.... nothing some help would really be aprreciated! thanks :) P.S I don't to edit my voice at all when I record and I would like it to stay that way since im thinking of possibly becoming a YouTube Let's Player of some sort.

Comment: is it 60 Hz (power line frequency) or 1 kHz (USB frame frequency)?

Comment: I can't tell it it's kind of high pitched but not that much im sure that it's from my power supply.... any suggestions?

Comment: Try plugging it into different USB ports or a powered hub

Comment: Tried every single usb port and it didn't fix it... can you send me a amazon link to a powered hub?

Comment: what are the 2 computers you've plugged it into?  was one plugged into the wall and the other on battery perhaps?

Comment: Im using a Desktop so yeah it's plugged into a wall.

Comment: Here is a test I made https://mega.co.nz/#!PRhRUBBC!dgF0u-DsuJnawj-QvGFxHpPN-iKQfzDDBihEtvjXaBc

Comment: One of the computers is my own which is a desktop and I tried my brother's computer which is also a desktop... on his desktop there was no humming at all and on my computer there is humming and no i don't have any consoles or fans running at all.

Comment: Is there a solution?